# Dropping too many frames in psychopy (python) while running a loading circle

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm new in python and psychopy, I have programmed a "loading circle", unfortunately I drop too many frames. I'm using a 60 Hz refresh rate, full screen, no internet connection, and the computer (a MacBook Pro) is powerful enough. Probably there's something wrong with my code (it's probably the setVertices method called in every frame), could someone please tell whether this is the case and whether there are alternatives in psychopy to draw a loading circle (without dropping too many frames)?
Thanks a lot
Emanuele

```
from psychopy import visual,event
import numpy
import math

mywin = visual.Window([1280, 800],monitor="testMonitor",units="deg",fullscr = True,winType='pyglet')
cir = visual.ShapeStim(mywin,lineWidth = 4,lineColor = 'black',closeShape = False)

class circ(object):
    def __init__(self,rad,size,centre):
        self.rad = rad
        self.size = size
        self.centre = centre
        self.points = numpy.arange(0,self.size, dtype = numpy.float)
def make_circle(self):
        self.cx = self.centre[0]+(self.rad*numpy.cos(self.points*math.pi/(self.size/2)))
        self.cy = self.centre[1]+(self.rad*numpy.sin(self.points*math.pi/(self.size/2)))
        return numpy.array([self.cx,self.cy])

nFrames = 240       
c = circ(3,nFrames,(0,0))
frames = numpy.zeros((nFrames,1),float)
coord = c.make_circle()
newpos=[]

for iframe in range(nFrames):
    newpos.append([coord[0,iframe],coord[1,iframe]])
    cir.setVertices(newpos)
    cir.draw()
    frames[iframe] = mywin.flip()
print numpy.diff(frames,axis = 0)*1000
```

Comment: It looks good and setting vertices should be fast enough here. Unfortunately my computer seems to have general vertical-sync problems right now, so I can't test it. For debugging, have you tried outcommenting setVertices in the loop? Or just presenting a simple ``visual.Circle(mywin, edges=128)`` with various number of edges? An alternative approach is to use a ``visual.RadialStim(mywin, visibleWedge=(0.90))`` as mask and then updating the ``visibleWedge``. Not sure if that would work satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, the problem is to be due to setVertices and increases over time, the more the array grows, the more it drops frames. The idea with visual.Circle and visual.RadialStim as mask seems to work better (I cannot properly test it right now) although the transitions are not so smooth. It seems to be a bit smoother using the pygame window instead of the pyglet one. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, then I was probably not right in my guess that ``ShapeStim`` would be fast enough for this. Another solution, instead of using a mask, is to simply draw a black ``RadialStim`` on top of the circle.

Comment: Hi @Jonas, thanks for the suggestion (I thought you actually meant that in your first comment). Interestingly, using the version with RadialStim, I got this warning 'Couldn't measure a consistent frame rate. - Is your graphics card set to sync to vertical blank?'. So probably the problem is due to the graphics card settings, and as far as I understood you have the same issue

Comment: What graphics card do you have? I have had multiple problems on laptops that have integrated intel graphics cards. One of my experiments would even hang on the same computer depending on whether I selected to run it with Nvidia card or integrated intel (I had both). (psychopy webpage discourages using computers with integrated graphics cards)

Comment: I have a NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB, I just tried my script on a windows machine and I did not see any problem with frames, so is it´s definetely a problem with the graphics card. Thanks  a lot